# Can I cause a Bleeding Fullstrike with a Concussive Weapon?

Tags: dead-winter-rpg

My 6th level Aldar, Cleric of Ligth, uses a Heavy Mace as her favourite weapon. While the  stun that comes with the "normal" Fullstrike of the Heavy Mace is pretty awesome, there's times that you can't really stun an enemy (as is the case of Dragon-Blooded characters, for example, or any Divine Offspring).

In those cases, Bleed Damage is still an option. Can I choose what kind of fullstrike I do with my weapon? Or are concussive weapons limited to the Stun Fullstrike?

Answer (score 4):

There's a feat for that:

> **Internal Hemorragy**: Critical hits that you make with a Concussive Weapon that stun the enemy by means of a fullstrike also cause Bleed 1.

That means, rougly, that when you hit someone really hard with a Concussive Weapon (gets a Crit) you also cause Bleed 1 if your crit turns up a fullstrike!

Comment: Please, don't put up direct quotes from the game guide without translating them to portuguese. Most people here can't read that if you let it in portuguese. Also: welcome!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will correct it!

Comment: @ThalesSarczuk Better?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.Stackexchange.com, good answer.